Is it possible to fix the issue where pressing Enter twice is recognized as only pressing it once?
After loading HTML into a QTextEdit and then trying to edit the content in QTextEdit, if I press Enter twice at the end of a line that contains '123' (with white space present), it is recognized as if I only pressed it once. Is there a way to fix this?
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QMainWindow
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # QTextEdit 생성
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        
        # HTML 문자열
        html_string = """
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
        <html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
        p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
        hr { height: 1px; border-width: 0; }
        li.unchecked::marker { content: "\2610"; }
        li.checked::marker { content: "\2612"; }
        </style></head><body style=" font-family:'맑은 고딕'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">123</p>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">123</p>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">123</p>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">123</p>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">123</p>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">123</p>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">123</p>
        <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><br /></p>
        </body></html>
        """
        
        # HTML 로드
        self.text_edit.setHtml(html_string)
        
        # QTextEdit 설정
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)
        self.setWindowTitle("QTextEdit HTML Example")
        self.resize(400, 300)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Documents must be saved and loaded as HTML.
It would be ideal if pressing Enter twice at the end of a string is recognized exactly as two presses.

The problem has nothing to do with the preceding string, but it's most certainly caused by a regression introduced at some point in Qt6 (see the possibly related QTBUG-120451 and QTBUG-119863). I cannot see an easy way to work around this right now.
